# How to fix “command not found” when it appears starting terminal on ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu

When I run the terminal in my elementary OS(Ubuntu 14.04 dist) it appears as follow:

```
Support: command not found
anargu@anargu-notebook-PC:~$
```

the first line (*Support: ...*) appeared after trying to install nodejs but I had problems to install it and I tried to install like 5 times in different ways and finally I could install it. But the "*Support: command not found*" appeared each time I run the terminal.

I'm new in ubuntu and I don't know what it refers with Support but I can type some commands like *ls, cd, sudo apt-get* and those work fine. So, please someone can help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You see this everytime you startup the terminal app?  Might be something hardcoded in your profile....( ~/.profile ) Edit/view this file to see if has any mention of the "support" cmd.  Also.....look for a strange configuration in your bashrc or a mistyped parameter in your launch-terminal command in your menu.  ( ~/.bashrc )

Comment: When you said that I have to check the "profile" you were talking about the .profile that is located in /home right??? I will check that. And Also i was checking the bashrc but I don't know how to interpret the code and how to identify if something is wrong.

Comment: I read .profile was only read when logging in the first time - if already logged in and open a terminal then just .basrc & maybe one other is run

Comment: To start try `grep Support ~/.*`... then if you find check from where it is called from. It's a row strart. Else more clean you can follow line by line your initialization files. You shoul find around the end if it is an addition. Last you shoul have eaten a `#` character somewhere especially if you edited by hand... good hunt.

Comment: Welcome aboard. Just curios - since you have posted on, and are aware of, our [Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/) and [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/)  sister sites, why ask this question here?

Comment: See [whenever I open my terminal it shows that `y` command not found what is problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1054074/whenever-i-open-my-terminal-it-shows-that-y-command-not-found-what-is-problem)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bash error "xxxxxx: command not found" shows up when you try to run a command/program that's not installed or not in the path, etc. Per Hastur's comment, searching for "Support" in .bashrc is a great idea, and check .login & .profile too if they exist (I don't think they should be running just for opening a terminal.

Could be in the `~/.bashrc` file. In general to find a mystery error I'd test it like this:

Try opening a terminal and type

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

If the error shows up, then it's definitely something in there that's the problem. Look through the file for the line that causes the error - could go line by line pasting into a terminal if it's not overwhelming, or add `echo "step 1"` ... `echo "step 2"` etc lines to narrow it down. Then remove/modify the offending line.

Comment: When I put in the terminal:
`source ~/.bashrc`
then the terminal returns another
`Support: command not found`
So I will check the file...

Comment: It does show up then? Just open & edit .bashrc then, and fix/remove/comment out the line that's got "Support ...." in it

Comment: Yes, I could solve the problem I think, because I just commented a piece of code then The "support command not found" dissapeared. The origin of the problem is because I installed nativescript (https://www.nativescript.org/) and part of this installations went to the bashrc file.

Answer (score 5):

Thanks Xen2050, I was checking my bashrc file (with echo "step1"...)and I found this part:

```
###-tns-completion-start-###
if [ -f /home/anargu/.tnsrc ]; then 
    source /home/anargu/.tnsrc 
fi
###-tns-completion-end-###
```

Well I coul identify it because I installed nativescript (https://www.nativescript.org/) and this part of code correspond to it. When I commented (put several "#") those lines, the:

`Support: command not found` just dissapeared.

I think I solved this problem just commenting that part of code because then I couldn't find any problem at the moment. Thank you so much!

Comment: No problem, I'll give it an upvote :) those lines source (like "read/load") the /home/anargu/.tnsrc file, it must contain the "Support ..." line, maybe it's a comment that's not commented, maybe there's a program that wasn't installed correctly, or something else. If there's anything else in that file you want/need you could fix it, but if everything works well now then why bother ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Answer by @Anargu lead me to the source of the problem. In `~/.tnsrc` I had a comment on the first line that hasn't actually been commented out. The first word of the statement was `Support`, that's why the error showed that word.

I've opened the file, deleted the line, and the error stopped showing up.